# How to setup "right-Alt + ." to print ">"

Tags: autohotkey

I have an English physical keyboard and need to use Spanish layout to use accents correctly. This makes it impossible to type ">" and "<" with ease. I want to bind the right-alt + . to the character ">".

Can I do this with Autohotkey? Any help is appreciated, the tutorials I've seen are too complicated. I managed to do it with a paid software called keyboard express 4, but I want a freeware option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indicate left/right keys with the [`< >`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#LeftRight) modifiers.
So, if your keyboard layout has an <kbd>RAlt</kbd> key: `>!.::SendInput, >`
And if your keyboard layout has an <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key: `<^>!.::SendInput, >` <sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#AltGr)</sup>

Comment: Thank you!! This was a solution to the issue. Now I just needed to execute on PC Start, any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Placing the script, or a shortcut to it, in `shell:startup` (type that into e.g. explorer address  bar or to Run (Win+R)) works.